# Google Inbox - for Google for Work (Apps)

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Is Google Inbox already habilitated for Google for Work (Apps) domains which are under Rapid Release cycle? I have received an invitation, but I can't seem to get into the Inbox site.

Comment: **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Google Inbox is not available for Google Apps accounts. They have not made any announcements about when that might change.

Answer (score 0):

From [Enable Inbox by Gmail for Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6082718?hl=en)

> ### Enable Inbox by Gmail
>
> You may receive requests from your users for access to Inbox by Gmail. Inbox by Gmail is a new product brought to you by the Gmail
>   Team. You can make Inbox by Gmail available for your invited users,
>   but it's not meant to replace Gmail. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/inbox?hl=en) about Inbox by Gmail.
>
> Only domains who receive an invitation may enable Inbox by Gmail. In
>   all cases the domain administrator will decide whether or not to
>   enable it for their domain or organizational unit. To request an
>   invitation to Inbox by Gmail for your Google Apps for Work domain,
>   please send an email to inboxforwork@google.com.